# my script repo became corrupted, apparently cross referencing a saved copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a longish script associated with a spreadsheet (over 500 lines), and saved a copy to have a backup. Somewhere along the line changes I made to the working script became ignored -- it would run the old version. new setValue statements were ignored for example, as were Logger.log methods. Renaming methods worked, although the previously named methods were still available.

I resolved it by deleting the copies (though one copy I tried to delete generated a system error on delete).

Eventually, I closed Chrome after deleting all script copies, and re-opened to find that deleted script copies were no longer listed, and recent changes to the working script were now being recognized.

Clearly the repo had become corrupted. Not a good sign.

Has anyone encountered this? Is this environment flaky? Am I in danger of losing my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't experienced this exact scenario, but I have experienced similar oddities that I attribute to the distributed nature of Google's architecture.

I don't think you are at risk of losing your code, I certainly have never lost anything over several years of working on the platform daily and with dozens of scripts across many accounts and domains.

The worst case fix I've had to use is making a fresh spreadsheet and moving my code and data into that new sheet to provide a "fresh start".

One situation that I have commonly had cause this kind of problem is if I copy and paste a large script "over top" of an existing script. EG in deploying from a "development" copy to a "live" copy.  On some occasions in that circumstance the newly pasted code is not recognized, the old code either continues to run, or I get errors saying the functions cannot be found.

My take on this is that your code gets compiled into some sort of executable at run time which is distributed out onto Google's servers, and on some occasions the linkage between the script you see in the script editor and that executable breaks down. But that is pure guesswork on my part.

Comment: I've never lost any code in dozens of scripts either, but had some rollbacks due to a couple of people having the same project open - not necessarily working on it or in the same script, just open. Eg. show.gs and hide.gs are in the same project, I'm working on show.gs and only it open, and a coleague is doing the same but with hide.gs, he saves last and I get a rollback in show.gs.

Comment: @Kriggs that's interesting and good to know, I rarely if ever have another coder working in the same document as me so I've never bumped into that issue in quite the same way. I was aware that changes made in the script don't propagate to other open copies in real-time, so I guess this outcome makes sense.  It would be nice if they had Docs style collaboration features.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check people, very helpful, and reassuring.